# delete all rows keep only one per hour group by strftime

Tags: sqlite, group-by, where-clause, sql-delete, sql-in

I have a [Home Assistant](https://www.home-assistant.io/) sqlite file.

My problem is that it grows fast and reaches enormous dimensions.
So I made a php script that cleans it every 24 hours.
I delete old and irrelevant data and leave only the data I need.

In addition I wanted to optimize the data I leave and delete for each sensor all the data except one value per hour, it will give me the information I need with all the graphs and reduce the file size.

I was thinking of using the `not in` option and wrote the following command:

```
 DELETE from states where state_id not in (select state_id, strftime ('% Y-% m-% d% H', last_changed, 'localtime') as date_hour from states group by entity_id, date_hour);
```

I sort all my sensors by sensor ID and by time and date and delete everything except one per hour.

But when I ran the command I got:
`Error: only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression`

Since I can not remove the date_hour column how do you guys think I should do it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery returns 2 columns so you must compare 2 columns against its results:

```
DELETE FROM states 
WHERE (entity_id, last_changed) NOT IN (
  SELECT entity_id, MAX(last_changed)
  FROM states 
  GROUP BY entity_id, strftime('%Y-%m-%d% %H', last_changed) 
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=70b10dfbcdffecfd78809a95f4a907f1).